# I am trying to populate data from table1 to table2 .Is my sql query correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

**table1**

```
 EID     EMPLOYEE_NAME       DESIGNATION               REPORTING_MANAGER    FLAG
    1        TIM COOK            CEO                   Null                 Null
    2        MILLER              CTO                   TIM COOK             Null
    3        BRAD                COO                   TIM COOK             Null
    4        WILLIAM             HRD                   TIM COOK             Null
    5        JOHN                TECH MANAGER(DEV)     WILLIAM              Null
    6        WALLACE             TECH MANAGER(TEST)    WILLIAM              Null
    7        SUNDAR              SWIFT DEV             JOHN                 Null
    8        PETER               SWIFT DEV             JOHN                 Null
    9        STEVE               TEST ENGINEER         WALLACE              Null
```

**table2**

```
 EID     EMPLOYEE_NAME      REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
```

I would like to generate something like below

```
EID     EMPLOYEE_NAME      REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
    1        TIM COOK          Null
    2        MILLER            1
    3        BRAD              1
    4        WILLIAM           1
    5        JOHN              4
    6        WALLACE           4
    7        SUNDAR            5
    8        PETER             5
    9        STEVE             6
```

I tried out the following query, it runs succesfully but doesn't insert data in table2.

---

```
INSERT INTO table2 (
    E_ID
    ,EMPLOYEE_NAME
    ,REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
    )
SELECT e.E_ID
    ,e.EMPLOYEE_NAME
    ,rm.E_ID AS REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
FROM table1 e
LEFT JOIN table1 rm ON rm.EMPLOYEE_NAME = e.REPORTING_MANAGER
WHERE e.FLAG = NULL
```

---

Someone help me out

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (E_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,REPORTING_MANAGER_ID) 
 SELECT e.E_ID , e.EMPLOYEE_NAME, rm.E_ID 
 FROM table1 e 
 LEFT JOIN table1 rm ON rm.EMPLOYEE_NAME = e.REPORTING_MANAGER 
 WHERE e.FLAG is NULL
```

If you compare a column with `null`, it returns `null`, which would return no rows from your `select` statement. Use `is null` instead.

Comment: Thanks VKP! One more help .is this correct ?  INSERT INTO table1(FLAG) values('1') WHERE FLAG is null

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned two queries will give the result which you required.

-- Using SubQuery

INSERT INTO table2
        (
        EID
        ,EMPLOYEE_NAME
        ,REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
        )
SELECT  t1.EID
        t1.Employee_Name,
        (
        SELECT    EID
        FROM      table1 t2
        WHERE     t1.EMPLOYEE_NAME = t2.REPORTING_MANAGER
        ) AS REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
FROM  table1 t1

--Using Join Condition

INSERT INTO table2
        (
        EID
        ,EMPLOYEE_NAME
        ,REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
        )
SELECT  t1.EID,
        t1.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
        t2.REPORTING_MANAGER
FROM    table1 t1
LEFT    OUTER JOIN table1 t2
ON      t1.EMPLOYEE_NAME = t2.REPORTING_MANAGER